# How do I make a clicke game run while closed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a clicker game stacking coins, and I want it to still gather coins while the user is away. The code I have at the moment for this is:

```
   public double coins = 0;
   public double coinsPerSecond = 10

   public void Update()
   {
     coins += coinsPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
   }
```

but that stops when the game is closed. How do I make it work then?
And in case that's not possible how do I trak the time the player was away?
i want it to be something like

```
   public double coins = 0;
   public double coinsPerSecond = 10;
   public double timeAway; //time measured in seconds

   public void Start()
   {
    coins += coinsPerSecond * timeAway;
   }
```

Comment: So you aren't going to use OnApplicationQuit and Playerprefs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function **OnApplicationQuit()** and save the time into the **PlayerPrefs**.This will be storing the time player had closed the game.

When the game is started up again, you can fetch the PlayerPrefs value and the current Time and subtract them both to get the time

Answer (score 1):

long time ago i did this. Save current time (when app is closing). When app is opening (y'know... initialize values), get current time, subtract previous and current one variable and calculate what you need